# Scroll-bar thumb color not working on ios (Iphone)

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, scrollview, scrollbar

## Scroll-bar thumb color not working on ios (Iphone)

### I added css for And it working fine on chrome and android phone

### I tred css

```
.horizontally-custom-scroll-tab{
    scrollbar-color: #1D497E #f1f1f1!important;
}
.horizontally-custom-scroll-tab.scrollbar-outer::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb,
.horizontally-custom-scroll-tab.scrollbar-outer::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal  {
    background-color: #1D497E !important;     
    background: #1D497E !important;    
     scrollbar-color: #1D497E #f1f1f1!important; 
}
.horizontally-custom-scroll-tab.scrollbar-outer:hover::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {background: #1D497E}
.horizontally-custom-scroll-tab.scrollbar-outer::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {background: #1D497E}
.horizontally-custom-scroll-tab.scrollbar-outer::-webkit-scrollbar-track{
    background:#f1f1f1
}
```

### js

```
 if (iOS) {
            $(".scrollbar-outer").removeClass('custom-scroll')
            jQuery('.scrollbar-outer').scrollbar();
        }
```